# Unable to find element by attribute with lxml

Tags: xpath, lxml, xml-attribute

I'm using a European Space Agency API to [**query**](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?q=footprint:%22Intersects(41.9000,%2012.5000)%22) (result can be viewed [**here**](https://pastebin.com/m2G1jatL)) for satellite image metadata to parse into python objects.

Using the `requests` library I can successfully get the result in XML format and then read the content with `lxml`. I am able to find the elements and explore the tree as expected:

```python
# loading the response into an ElementTree
tree = etree.fromstring(response.content)
root = tree.getroot()
ns = root.nsmap

# get the first entry element and its summary
e = root.find('entry',ns)
summary = e.find('summary',ns).text

print summary
```

`>> 'Date: 2018-11-28T09:10:56.879Z, Instrument: OLCI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-3, Size: 713.99 MB'`

The entry element has several *date* descendants with different values of the attriubute *name*:

```python
for d in e.findall('date',ns):
    print d.tag, d.attrib
```

`>> {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date {'name': 'creationdate'}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date {'name': 'beginposition'}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date {'name': 'endposition'}
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date {'name': 'ingestiondate'}`

I want to grab the *beginposition* date element using XPath syntax `[@attrib='value']` but it just returns None. Even just searching for a date element with the name attribute (`[@attrib]`) returns None:

```python
dt_begin = e.find('date[@name="beginposition"]',ns) # dt_begin is None
dt_begin = e.find('date[@name]',ns)                 # dt_begin is None
```

The entry element includes other children that exhibit the same behaviour e.g. multiple *str* elements also with differing *name* attributes.

Has anyone encountered anything similar or is there something I'm missing? I'm using Python 2.7.14 with lxml 4.2.4

Comment: When trying to access the resource linked in the question, I am prompted for username and password. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn I've added a link to the result on pastebin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an explicit prefix is needed when a predicate (`[@name="beginposition"]`) is used. Here is a test program:

```
from lxml import etree

print etree.LXML_VERSION

tree = etree.parse("data.xml")  

ns1 = tree.getroot().nsmap
print ns1
print tree.find('entry', ns1)
print tree.find('entry/date', ns1)
print tree.find('entry/date[@name="beginposition"]', ns1)

ns2 = {"atom": 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
print tree.find('atom:entry', ns2)
print tree.find('atom:entry/atom:date', ns2)
print tree.find('atom:entry/atom:date[@name="beginposition"]', ns2)
```

Output:

```
(4, 2, 5, 0)
{None: 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'opensearch': 'http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'}
<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry at 0x7f8987750b90>
<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date at 0x7f89877503f8>
None
<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry at 0x7f8987750098>
<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date at 0x7f898774a950>
<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}date at 0x7f898774a7a0>
```

Comment: Thanks for this concise example. I see now that using the predicates requires the explicit use of namespaces including the default namespace. On the other hand if a predicate is not used in the find/findall method the default namespace does not have to be explicitly stated.

Comment: I am still a bit confused, to be honest... I don't really understand why it works like this. When using `xpath()` instead of `find()` or `findall()`, a prefix is always required (with or without a predicate).

Comment: Yeah, I do find it strange. I've not been able to find any documentation that explains clearly why there are these different behaviours.